# Questão em leitura e impressão de nomes com char

Tags: c, lógica

Eai galera. Eu estou tentando criar um código que **lê, armazena e imprime nomes de no máximo 5

letras(Caracteres)**.
Tenho certeza que deve haver **um jeito mais ágil que esse que eu fiz**, logo abaixo:
**OBS:** Quero poder ler e imprimir nomes com ATE 5 LETRAS. Sei que há maneiras mais ageis com
Stings mas quero aprender assim.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    main (){
        char nome[4];
        printf("Qual o seu nome?\n");  
        scanf("%c%c%c%c ", &nome[0],&nome[1],&nome[2],&nome[3],&nome[4]); 
        printf("O seu nome é:%c%c%c%c%c",nome[0],nome[1],nome[2],nome[3],nome[4]); 
    }
```

Comment: Reposta satisfatória, obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Esse é o usual:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main (void)
    {
        char nome[6];
        printf("Qual o seu nome? ");  
        int res = scanf("%5s", nome );
        printf( "[scanf() retornou %d]\t", res);
        if ( res == 1 ) printf("O seu nome: \"%s\"\nprimeira letra: '%c'\n",nome, nome[0]); 
        printf("\n"); 
        return 0;
    }
```

Isso que quer usar se chama string em C, e é um vetor com um zero no fim --- null terminated, na literatura. `scanf()` le essas coisas com o especificador `%s` `%5s` limita o tamanho em 5 letras. Como tem o tal zero no fim deve declarar o nome com 6 ou não vai caber. As letras são acessadas pelo índice. Veja no exemplo.

Teste sempre o retorno de `scanf()`, que pode ser -1, 0, 1.. até o total de especificadores que usou. Ex: `scanf(%5s,%d,%d,%f" ... )` pode ler até 4 campos (nesse caso separados por vírgulas) e então scanf() pode retornar -1 em caso de erro, ou 0, 1, 2, 3 ou 4 conforme tenha conseguido ler esse número de campos.

Sugiro não pular de linha depois do prompt ao ler algo: em geral as pessoas se sentem mais à vontade lendo a pergunta e digitando a resposta na mesma linha...

#### Saída do exemplo:

```
so>  gcc -o tst -Wall x078b.c
so>  ./tst
Qual o seu nome? abcde
[scanf() retornou 1]    O seu nome: "abcde"
primeira letra: 'a'

so>  ./tst
Qual o seu nome? abcdef
[scanf() retornou 1]    O seu nome: "abcde"
primeira letra: 'a'

so>  ./tst
Qual o seu nome? ^Z
[scanf() retornou -1]
so>
```

Answer (score -1):

Boa noite, amigo. Como você dize existe formas melhores de fazer essa leitura, mas como você optou por uma específica irei de ajudar.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void main(){
    char nome[6];
    printf("Qual o seu nome?\n");  
    scanf("%c%c%c%c%c", &nome[0],&nome[1],&nome[2],&nome[3],&nome[4]); 
    printf("O seu nome e: %c%c%c%c%c\n",nome[0],nome[1],nome[2],nome[3],nome[4]); 

}
```

Explicação:

Ao declarar o arranjo de char você deveria ter colocado 'nome[6]' ao invés de 'nome[4]'. Deve ser feito assim, pois ao declarar um arranjo de char deve-se levar em conta que a última posição será reservada ao caracter'\n'.

Exemplo:

'nome[4]' seria declarado da seguinte forma: 'D', 'a', 'v', 'i'

'nome[6]' seria declarado da seguinte forma: 'D', 'a', 'v', 'i', 'd', '\n'

Perceba que na segundo exemplo tem os 5 espaços para as letras e um espaço para o '\n' (caracter importante em um arranjo de char). A primeiro exemplo a letra 'i' basicamente "invade" o lugar do '\n', isso não é algo positivo.

Também aconteceu alguns outros problemas de sintaxe no código.

São eles:

Linha 3: deve ser declarado um tipo de retorno ou um 'void' à função main

Linha 6: foi colocado um espaço após declarar os '%c'. Modo correto: "%c%c%c%c".

Linha 6: foi colocado somente quatro '%c' sendo que deveria ser cinco.

Comment: Acho que você confundiu o `\0`, caractere nulo, com o `\n`, caractere que quebra a linha. E um detalhe é que se você fizer a leitura de todas as posições do vetor usando o `%c`, então deve colocar o `\0` de forma manual (`vetor[6] = '\0';`).

Comment: Sim, bem observado. 
Acabei confundido. 
Obrigado por reportar